# Quadratic program with non-linear stochastic contraint

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization

I am interested in methods to solve the following optimization problem:

\begin{align}
\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \ (x-x_0)^TQ(x-x_0)\quad \text{subject to} \quad \mathbb{E}_\omega[g(x)]=g_0
\end{align}
In the above $Q$ is assumed to be positive definite and $g(x)$ is a random variable which additionally depends on $x$. If $g$ were deterministic I could just apply regular Lagrangian multiplier theory. However, I don't know how to deal with the stochasticity of $g$. Is there some Robbins-Monro type algorithm for these kinds of problems?

Comment: What do you know about the random variable (function)? How do or can you either exactly or approximately evaluate its expectation for a given $x$?

Comment: the random variable corresponds to a very complex simulation model. I therefore cannot do much more than just sampling from it.

Comment: That is an expected value constraint. You will need to do something along the lines of Sample Average Approximation. Your problem is not the same as the following due to having equality rather than inequality constraint, gut this should give you some ideas https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~sahmed/evc.pdf .Overall, not so easy.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I checked out the paper. Besides the inequality constraint the paper assumes that $g$ can be directly expressed as a function of $x$ and some random variables $Z$. In my case, however, it is close to impossible to get a closed form function for that. The only thing I can do is pick an $x$ and run the full simulation (which entails many, many RVs entering the model at different times during the simulation).

Comment: Could I just apply deterministic optimization methods replacing the corresponding derivatives of $g$ with sample averages (e.g. finite differences)? Or are there any other methods?

Comment: You are better off if you can use automatic differentiation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation on the simulation, presuming it has the requisite continuity per sample path, and then sampling that automatic derivative several times to estimate the derivative. There are a number of tools in various languages and environments for automatic differentiation - but you need access to source code.

Comment: I already had this in mind but it seems impossible to do. I would need to rewrite great parts of the simulation code which is not feasible under the time constraints I have for the project.

Comment: Well, then finite difference using common random numbers for the points being differenced. But fi your simulation is not written with this in mind, you may not get good synchronization, and therefore little correlation in the nearby points being differenced, which if you had it, could greatly increase accuracy of derivative estimate.